# Search settings - on the search page, add a web part "others also searched"

Tags: web-part, search, enterprise-search, web-analytics

On the page, you need to perform a search, add the "others also searched" web part. What displays the words that users are looking for along with the current text in the search.

How can this be realized? Preferably, using the built-in functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the "Popular Searches" web part available in SharePoint 2010 has been removed from SharePoint 2013.

To impement the same functionality within SharePoint 2013 refer to the following article: [Recreating the Popular Searches Web Part in SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nathan_brackett/2015/11/11/recreating-the-popular-searches-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013/)